# What is the meaning of "do not populate test points" in a board schematic

Tags: embedded, schematics, testing

I was finding test points in a schematic of an Analog Devices Evaluation board. In one of the schematic pages, there is a clause mentioned **"do not populate test points**".

Does anyone knows what it means ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means they are points provided for testing purposes so do not connect components etc to those points.

Comment: Additionally, it is an easy way to exclude a component from BOM (as TP have reference designators) , some EDA have special component type for test points that do not require this work around, but even then  Often a PCB assembly house will inquire about missing designators between CAD data and the  BOM . so an explicit DNP is a normal engineering style to address this when there is a production requirement  to check BOM and CAD for consistency.

Answer (score 12):

Test points are very useful during development.  A test point can be a flat SMT pad, or a throughole pad.  Sometimes, a test point has a loop for clipping a probe onto ([throughole examples](https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Test-Points-Tips-Probes-Clips/Test-Points-color-keyed-Thru-Hole-Mount/p/518/id/521), [SMT examples](https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Test-Points-Tips-Probes-Clips/Test-Points-Surface-Mount-Miniature-Compact/p/518/id/523)).  Sometimes, these loops are used only during R&D testing.  In mass production the test points are contacted by automated test equipment, and the loops aren't installed in production to save cost.

Comment: I love test points, having worked on boards without them for a year.

Comment: @DKNguyen For sanity's sake, at least a ground testpoint for a scope probe, please.